# Как задать обводку у текста в TextBlock?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Стандартными средствами не нашёл как это сделать в UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая возможность, похоже, [отсутствует](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/7077918-enable-text-effects-in-windows-runtime-xaml-apps).

Comment: @Horoko, Но если очень хочется, то можно добавить самому. Интересующую информацию можно извлечь из [этой](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2014/01/Character-Formatting-Extensions-with-DirectWrite.html) статьи Чарльза Петцольда

Comment: @ixSci да похоже придётся как и все использовать просто бэкграунд текст блока, для его выделения на фоне.